# Matlab slider pass value to event handler

Tags: matlab, user-interface, slider, handler

I am new of Matlab GUI and i have the following problem.
I have declared a slider control and his properties, and i have added a listerner to the callback and to the PostSet event handler (i think that it is  tecnically called event handler) as you can see below:

```
function [] = HandlerSlide()
%HANDLERSLIDE Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
clf;
due = '2';
hSlider = uicontrol(                ...
    'Style','slider',               ...
    'Callback',@(s,e) disp(['hello ',num2str(due),' asdad']),...
    'Position', [400 30 200 20]     ... %[x,y, widht, height]
);
hListener = addlistener(hSlider,'Value','PostSet',@pippo);


end

function [] = pippo(s,e)

disp('ciao');

end
```

As you can see i have used parameter "*due*" in the Callback handler (the  anonymous function). Now i would like to pass parameter to use in the "*pippo*" function without declare it as anonymous function. Is it possible?
In other words i would like to declare "*hListerner*" like this:

```
hListener = addlistener(hSlider,'Value','PostSet',@pippo{parameter1,parameter2, etc ...});

function[] = pippo(s,e, parameter1, parameter2, etc ...)
```

Beside how can i use in the main the value returned by "*pippo*"?

thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

Inputs in handle functions are added like that:

```
hListener = addlistener(hSlider,'Value','PostSet',{@pippo,parameter1,parameter2});
```

You have to be careful then in the function, as "parameter1" won't be the first input but the third (after source and eventdata).

Comment: thank you but i tried to write this: 
hListener = addlistener(hSlider,'Value','PostSet',{@pippo,'string'}); linked to the function: function [] = pippo(s,e,var)

disp(var);

end
 But i received this error: Error using HandlerSlide (line 48)
No method 'addlistener' with matching signature found. Callback must be a function handle.
 Sorry but i am really new to the listener mechanism :(

Comment: Ok, otherwise you could put the 'pippo' function INSIDE the 'HandlerSlide' one. The variables become " global" within a function (not sure how to call it, I'm no IT person).